# C++ why accessing elements outside of an array is allowed even though it is undefined?

Tags: c++, arrays, arrayaccess

I was wondering why accessing elements outside of array bound is allowed when it is clearly mentioned as undefined.

Comment: Basically because protecting the developer from themselves isn't always free. If you want runtime protection you can ask for it by using `std::vector::at` but you pay the performance hit of having every access checked.

Comment: so, is it performance related?

Comment: Correct, 100% performance related.  Performance is one of the touchstones of C++.

Comment: c++ has a principle of not paying for what you don't need. If it checked every time for out of bounds there would be a non zero time cost to do so.

Comment: Note that compiling your code with (the tremendously expensive) `-fsanitize=undefined` or `-fsanitize=address` *will* result in a process-terminating runtime error.

Comment: The issue also has to do with code space.  Many embedded systems have limited memory area for code.  There is a tradeoff on error checking and code space.